# MySQL Count rows From Table WHERE userid equals? - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am having trouble with MySQL in CodeIgniter, I have the 3 columns:

```
ID  |  USERID  |  NAME    |  MOBILE
1        1         JAMES      55
2        1         JOHN       66
3        2         ANNE       33
```

I want to count the number of rows where the USERID is 1 in CodeIgniter, anyone can help me?

I expect the output will be 2, because there is 2 records assigned to the USERID 1.

Thanks

Comment: is this your homework? have you tried anything? i don't think so

Comment: yes it's for a little learning project, making a simple address book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('USERID',1);
$this->db->from('my_table');
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select count(userid) from table where userid=1
```

Answer (score 0):

**CodeIgniter Model**

```
function count($userid){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table_name');
    $this->db->where('userid',$userid);
   return  $this->db->get()->num_rows();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table where USERID = 1');
echo $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I already tried, at the moment I have 21 records in my database but only 5 is assigned to the USERID 1, and the code you gave is returning all the records in this table (21). Thank you